# EF core list of string datatype to postgresql

Tags: c#, .net, postgresql, entity-framework

I am using **EF core 1.1.1 & postgresql** with code-first implementation.

I have a model class with member variable for List as follow.

```
public class user : IdentityUser
{
    public int id { get; set; }
    [Column("devices", TypeName = "text[]")]
    public List<string> devices { get; set; };
}
```

I declared datatype as text[] and it shows as text array in database. Saving to database as follow works.

```
var device = "phone";
user.devices.Add(device);
```

It stores data in database but it returns an error when I try to call query like this.

```
if (user.Any(x => x.devices.Count > 0))
```

Showing error like this.

> Can't cast database type _text to List`1'

How can I convert stored text data to List?

Thanks.

Answer (score 5):

Late but still - use `string[]` instead of `List<string>`.

```
public string[] Devices { get; set; }
```

Bad news is that you cannot use the `x => x.Devices.Count > 0` lambda anyway when querying directly from DB, since the EF+Npgsql still cannot convert these expressions into SQL (at least in versions <= 1.1.0...)
You'll have to write this condition in raw SQL.

```
var result = db.YourTable
   .FromSql("select * from your_table where array_length(devices) > 0")
   .Where(...)
   .OrderBy(...)
   ...
   .ToList();
```

Filtering fetched rows in memory works normally, of course.

Comment: Thanks for pointing in the right direction for a similar issue:  My solution was essentially: `var IList<string> list = (string[])reader.GetValue(reader.GetOrdinal("column"));`  - so the property was `IList` and GetValue cast to `string[]` converted between them.

Comment: Why should he use array instead of list?